# How to replace the newline in a variable with comma in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have a variable foo .

echo "print foo" "$foo"
---> a
b
c

Expected output :
I want the output to be comma separated like below

a,b,c

I tried foo|grep '^>' |sed -e "s/^>/,/"

but it is appending comma before.
Result :
,a ,b ,c

Which is wrong.

Comment: Needed one more help, how can i get the below result?                                                                      'a','b','c'

Answer (score 2):

With bash:

```sh
foo='a
b
c'
joined="${foo//$'\n'/,}"
echo "$joined"
```

```
a,b,c
```

For portability, using dash:

```sh
IFS="
"       # just a quoted newline
set -f  # turn off filename expansion
set -- $foo
IFS=,
joined="$*"
echo "$joined"
```

This can be made into a function:

```sh
join_lines() {
  local IFS=${1:-,}
  set --
  while IFS= read -r line; do set -- "$@" "$line"; done
  echo "$*"
}
```

So you can do

```sh
echo "$foo" | join_lines      # => a,b,c
echo "$foo" | join_lines "|"  # => a|b|c
```

---

Or, sed

```sh
echo "$foo" | sed -n "s/^/'/; s/\$/',/; H; \$ {g; s/\n//g; s/,\$//; p;}"
```

Comment: Needed one more help, how can i get the below result? 'a','b','c'

Comment: In the function, you'd use `set -- "$@" "'$line'"`

Comment: Is there any other way around without using with function

Comment: I wanted to do with bash

Comment: the function is actually appending quotes before and after variable,

Answer (score 0):

Go for replacing spaces with commas:

```
echo "$foo" | sed -e 's/\ /,/g'
```

You don't even need to use sed, this one is bash [replacement](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) construct (look under *Substring Replacement* topic):

```
echo "${foo//\ /,}"
```

Comment: Can I store the result in a variable?

Comment: I tried this way : check=${foo//\ /,}
echo "print the result:" "$check"

Comment: That's exactly how you'd do that

Comment: It's giving me blank this way